# Firefox does not use default window bar appearance when running as Snap

Tags: 20.04, firefox, snap, 22.04

Today I upgraded my Ubuntu from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS. As announced, Firefox is now running as a Snap package by default. While the application is running fine, I noticed some weird behavior in the appearance of the window bar.

This is how the window bar looks with Firefox as a snap:

[image: Firefox with different window bar appearance]

This is how the window bar looks with any other snap I have installed, here it's KeepassXC:

[image: Normal looking window bar]

To me it looks as if Firefox uses some other theme and does not respect the system's theme settings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Snap ignores your theme and selects one of the co-packed snap themes. This is one of the drawbacks of snap.

You could remove Firefox from snap with:

```
sudo snap disable firefox
snap remove --purge firefox
```

For Ubuntu 22.04, the empty Firefox Deb is pre-installed as a wrapper. You have to remove it via command:

```
sudo apt remove --autoremove firefox
```

On Ubuntu 22.04, you'll have to add a ppa now:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
```

Now you can install it as deb:

```
sudo apt install -t 'o=LP-PPA-mozillateam' firefox
```

To avoid clashes during the next updates you might setup the priority in the mozillas ppa file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences.d/99mozillateamppa
```

Below the existing lines add the following entries:

```
Package: firefox*
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 501
```

To block Ubuntu's own (empty) deb add these lines as well:

```
Package: firefox*
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: -1
```

This all has been explained [here](https://fostips.com/ubuntu-21-10-two-firefox-remove-snap/) in detail

I removed snap altogether, because I want to have the freedom to decide about the look & feel of my desktop - uniformly ;-)

Comment: Great description. This resolves my issue although I wish Snap/Firefox would respect this more :-)