# I have a /home partition separated and would like to move /snap to my home as snap is eating my root disk space. Is there any possibility to do that?

Tags: 20.04, partitioning, kde, snap

So I have separated my /home partition (I always recommend doing that) and I have some space available there. But my / partition is with less than 1GB and I have to clean snap every once and then to try to get more space. Is there any way to move the /snap directory to inside my /home?. I'm using focal fossa.

Comment: How about removing it altogether? I've described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403392/906933) how to do it

Comment: Please remove the rambling from your question and just ask the question itself. Personal opinions do not matter here.

Comment: This does not make much sense, the `/snap` directory contains only mountpoints, means here are your snaps mounted, but the real snap files are in `/var/lib/snapd/snaps`.

Comment: Thanks all for the help, Vanadium it doesn't matter the euphemism used I could have used "consuming" my space instead of eating and you still would understand very well what it means. I asked for help on a problem and gave the reason for that before somebody asks why you want to do that. So, crystal clear. Unfortunetley I can't stop using it right now @kanehekili and mook765 yes it contains just mount points but you have to have the space so it can mounted there. I found a remedy here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029562/move-snap-packages-to-another-location-directory,