# Firefox AND Chrome refuse to download anything except in Downloads folder

Tags: firefox, downloads, 22.04

This is Ubuntu 22.04, x86_64. Any download I make from either browser just isn't done, and silently. It just proceeds, does not show me any error message, and no file appears. When the selected folder is the default `Downloads` folder (I configured both browsers to ask), the download happens normally. Smells like a security thing, but there's no user feedback.

In Firefox, I tried setting `browser.download.improvements_to_download_panel` in `about:config` to False. No effect.

Comment: It is a snap thing.

Comment: Both browsers are available as deb... Check [my anwer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403392/906933) on how to install it as deb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following directions similar to [these](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/install-firefox-deb-ubuntu-22-04/):

```
sudo snap remove firefox
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
```

Then put the following in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox`:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: firefox*
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: -1
```

Then

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

The .deb is at version 100 now and it works perfectly well. Downloads to anywhere too.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of Ubuntu use snap to install and run Firefox. Nowadays only right way to install Firefox is to remove snap Firefox, download Firefox from [Mozilla site](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/all/#product-desktop-release) and unpack to **~/firefox**
Then just run **~/firefox/firefox**
In the case Firefox can use its own auto update system.

You will not find another **right** way to do it. No relevant official PPA (for current release), no official flatpak, no official AppImage. You can find **.deb** but most likely it will be outdated build made for Ubuntu or Debian. Ubuntu and Debian make new Firefox builds very slow, may takes weeks after release.

Comment: I am not supporting snaps but can you explain why snap is the problem a bit more clearer?

Comment: @yangmandi because snap actually is not prepared for production release, it has lack of functionality, but Canonical (Ubuntu developer) need to show that they spend money not for nothing and snap is useful. Also they use user Ubuntu to test snap in real life to use snap in Ubuntu then (and make some money from it). Canonical may say that it is because of "snap use isolation to protect you" but of course it is a lie, if you do not have some functionality then it is not a feature, it is a bug. And use that functionality in Ubuntu LTS is not right way.