# Firefox migration to snap breaks native messaging extensions

Tags: upgrade, firefox, snap, 22.04, firefox-extensions

After the forced migration of Firefox from deb to snap after upgrading from 21.10 to 22.04 all my native messaging extensions stopped working.

**File this for me**
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/file-this-for-me/

**Open with anything**
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-with-anything/

They're still installed but do not show up as a context menu.

Debugging the extension I get this error:

```
Error: Error: Attempt to postMessage on disconnected port
```

Normally that message is shown when Firefox can't find the [host manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging#setup)

To fix that problem copy the old `~/.mozilla/native-messaging-hosts` dir to `~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/

Not sure why that is not done by default in the migration.

Restart Firefox and now at least the functionality shows up in the context menu.

Still not working though, now I get another **not very helpful** error:

```
Error: Error: An unexpected error occurred
```

My guess the path for the binary is sandboxed or so.

BTW I did find a open Firefox [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1661935)
and [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1741074)

This is a major functionality setback for Ubuntu users, any solutions/workarounds yet?

I do not get the forced migration to snap: slower start and lost functionality.

Comment: The upstream bug report for native messaging is already at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1661935. There is a fix currently in testing: https://phabricator.services.mozilla.com/D140803 . Canonical engineers livestreamed a Firefox Snap Question/Answer event, including how users (like you and me) can help fix the slow-starting issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHFXB6VSS0w . The 'forced migration' was driven by Mozilla, not by Ubuntu or Canonical. The Desktop Team manager has called this his #1 issue, and updating weekly: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/c/desktop/team-updates/23

Comment: You might be interested in how to get out of Firefox Snap Hell: https://askubuntu.com/q/1399383/243321

Comment: Guess have to wait for the bug fix then. Thx for all the links, since the last FF update the slow start has improved IMHO, it's better. https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-are-we-improving-firefox-snap-performance-part-1

Comment: And see here:https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/known-issues-with-firefox-snap/24663/67

Comment: I don't use snap. You might check [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403392/906933) on how to remove the snap version and get the "original" firefox