# Disabling Firefox snap permanently to use Firefox from .deb/apt

Tags: software-installation, firefox, 22.04, snap, ppa

For security reasons, I run Firefox under a separate user account rather than my main account. That user is not configured to start snap programs, so if snap Firefox is installed, Firefox cannot start at all.

So I always want to use the Firefox via apt.

I have  followed the steps from [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22) to install apt Firefox. That installs Firefox from apt and it works fine.

But after every update, the snap Firefox is installed again. Then I have to uninstall the snap and install the apt version again. I want to kill it off permanently

I have done the steps from [Completely remove firefox snap package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414173/completely-remove-firefox-snap-package) (`snap disable firefox && sudo snap remove --purge firefox`) but they do not help  and the snap keeps coming back.

Policy:

```
$  apt policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 110.0+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1
  Candidate: 110.0+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1
  Version table:
     1:1snap1-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
 *** 110.0+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1 1001
       1001 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Do you need to preserve the ability to run any other snaps?

Comment: You can use apt-pinning for the ppa. Give a value over 1000.

Comment: Did you set up the apt pin file as in this answer? https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi: I have a pin file with the first three lines "Package: * Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam Pin-Priority: 1001"

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the output of `apt policy firefox`?

Comment: @OrganicMarble: It is probably better if it is preserved

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi: I added it

Comment: I have answered it [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403392/906933)